# Convert contents of Array List to String

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I've been trying to turn this Array list of Terms (Letters and Numbers) into a String, (unless its `1`, in which case the program should ignore the element).

Is this the proper way to go about accomplishing this or should I use a different method?

My code is as follows:

```
public String display() {

    for (int i = 0; i < terms.size(); i++) {

        char p = terms.get(i);

        if(Character.isDigit(p = 1)) {
            continue;
        } else if (Character.isDigit(p)) {
            return String.valueOf(p);
        } else {
            return Character.toString(p);
        }
    }

    p = display(); 
    return display();
}
```

**Note**: I know this is wrong - I just need someone to point me in the right direction.

Input Example:
{Term('C', 1),Term('O',2)} would give "CO2"

Comment: Where is `terms` defined? What is its specific type? Is it a `List` of generic type? If so, which type?

Comment: Also this should generate an endless recursion.

Comment: Can you show an input example and the expected output?

Comment: terms is an arraylist

Comment: @Alfred : please share the complete code and expected input and output

Comment: You haven't answered the question. Is it a raw-type ArrayList? Is it generic? If so, which type? Simply provide its definition to avoid confusion.

Comment: the question was does it have a generic type? as in `Arraylist<Something>`

Comment: Check StringUtils.join, it might be doing just what you need.

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras, if you mention a 3rd party lib, please provide full info how to get it or at least its name, otherwise ppl will think this is part of JDK .  in this case, it is Apache Commons Lang

Comment: Sorry yeah, it's defined as: new ArrayList<Term>();

Comment: Yeah sorry if it seemed that way sharonbn. Also java 8 supports the String.join() function straight from the jdk. You can alos override the toString() method of class Term to return the value you want.

Comment: Okay, so now please edit with the `Term` class, so we can now its fields and methods and how to use it in order to help you.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by `if (Character.isDigit(p = 1))` - this is assigning a value to `p` which overwrites `char p = terms.get(i);`. It will always be false, because `\u0001` isn't a digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Term is some custom class like below (based on the sample input you have mentioned):

```
public class Term{
    private String element;
    private int number;
    public String getElement(){
        return element;
    }
    public void setElement(char element){
        this.element = element;
    }
    public int getNumber(){
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(int number){
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

Your concatenation method can be something like this:

```
public String display() {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(50);
    for (int i = 0; i < terms.size(); i++) {
        Term p = terms.get(i);
        sb.append(p.getElement());
        if(p.getNumber()!=1) {
            sb.append(p.getNumber());
        } 
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestSkack {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<KeyValue> terms=new ArrayList<>();

        terms.add(new KeyValue('C', 1));
        terms.add(new KeyValue('O', 2));
        System.out.println(display(terms));

    }

    public static String display(List<KeyValue> terms){
        String result="";
        for(KeyValue keyValue:terms){
            if(keyValue.getValue()==1)
                result+=keyValue.getKey();
            else
                result+=String.valueOf(keyValue.getKey())+keyValue.getValue();
        }
        return result;
    }
}

class KeyValue{
    Character key;
    Integer value;


    public KeyValue(Character key, Integer value) {
        super();
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
    public Character getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public void setKey(Character key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
    public Integer getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }


}
```